# How to implement a share your result button on Facebook quiz app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Ok so I want to create a Facebook quiz app where the user are shown some results like
`john is your best friend!`

I have generated an image of the result and want to share the image along with the link of the quiz page. After a bit of search I found out that `FB.ui` with `method: "feed"` can be used for this, but it looks like the API have changed a little and now the image share doesn't work like it used to. If I include `link: "somelink"` then it pulls the images and description from the `somelink` instead of using the image mentioned in  `picture: "someimage",`.

So how would I go about implementing this type of share now? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to generate a separate (random) Perma-URL for the result, including the image as og:image tag.

The feed dialog had some parameters for those things ("caption", for example), but they are all deprecated too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

Comment: Yeah this is viable as well. But i am trying to implement this without a backend if possible. Looks like that will not be possible after all

Comment: Are quiz apps like these made using this method or as a Facebook games? Do you think it makes sense to implement this as a game? This app will have some interactive elements but the main things is still sharing. Will implementing it as a game allow sharing results more easily?

Comment: for sharing, there should not be any big difference between games or other apps, so i assume they are using the same concept.